# Add option to disable comments on a per posts basis?

Tags: comments

IN the past I thought there was a chackbox to enable/disable comments when making a new posts?  I do not have that option when I make new post's, please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on `Screen options` in the top right corner of the screen. And select `Discussion`. Than you'll see that checkbox to enable/disable comments. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Look in the top right corner of the screen for view options. Click the link to reveal a drop-down. That has check-box options. One of them will say discussions. Click it and you should see the allow/disallow comments check-boxes.